# Farbic SVG path length calculation

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I am new with fabric. Currently I am working with paths. Below line (Shown in image) is created by fabric now I need to calculate the length of this length (X in image). Fabric is only able to give me width of blue box which is 390px;

Path d: **M 10 10 Q 10 10 400 0** (OR Any)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `fabric.util.getPathSegmentsInfo` method calculates the length along each part of the path. The last value in the array contains the total path length.

```
var pathInfo = fabric.util.getPathSegmentsInfo(obj.path);
var totalPathLength = pathInfo[pathInfo.length - 1].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getTotalLength:

```
const length = document.getElementById([my_path_id]).getTotalLength();
```

Comment: Its not possible with fabric as we don't have any document.